# Converting CSV to Column separated values but placing the values most right

Tags: shell, debian, cat

Concept is a debian running computer with an SH script file in retrieving data.

I have searched on how to convert data from csv back to columns and rows. This was fairly easy. 
for instance, i have this:

[image]

And using this command: `column -t -s, >` this will gives me this:

```
Date        SkyT_Min  SkyT_Min_Time  SkyT_Max  SkyT_Max_Time  SkyT_Mean  AmbT_Min  AmbT_Min_Time  AmbT_Max  AmbT_Max_Time
2019-09-19  -22.8     07:29:48.00    -1.6      12:27:57.00    -16.77     5.9       05:15:11.00    23.4      14:28:49.00  
2019-09-25  -15.8     11:49:40.00    9.1       20:17:11.00    1.07       14.7      02:47:10.00    21.7      11:46:38.00  
2019-09-26  -9.6      02:59:29.00    10.8      11:09:18.00    5.66       16.4      20:58:37.00    23.4      14:08:58.00
```

So overall that is already great!

But how do i get it to get the values in each column to start on the far right, instead on the left? 
So i would get something like this:

[image]

Thank you very much for your answer.

UPDATE:

I have found the answer to my question:

[--R](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html#AVAILABILITY)

But it gives me errors: "invalied option -- 'R'

So if anyone has any idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can work with awk:

- -F tells awk the column separator
- "%20s " tells awk to reserve 20 characters for each column and to concat a whitespace to each entry

```
awk -F "," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%20s ", $i}; printf "\n"}' inputfile.csv
```

Output:

```
                Date             SkyT_Min        SkyT_Min_Time             SkyT_Max        SkyT_Max_Time            SkyT_Mean             AmbT_Min        AmbT_Min_Time             AmbT_Max        AmbT_Max_Time 
          2019-09-19                -22.8          07:29:48.00                 -1.6          12:27:57.00               -16.77                  5.9          05:15:11.00                 23.4          14:28:49.00 
          2019-09-25                -15.8          11:49:40.00                  9.1          20:17:11.00                 1.07                 14.7          02:47:10.00                 21.7          11:46:38.00 
          2019-09-26                 -9.6          02:59:29.00                 10.8          11:09:18.00                 5.66                 16.4          20:58:37.00                 23.4          14:08:58.00
```

P.S.: Please avoid screenshots in the future because [nobody likes them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).